# grunt sass and js autoloader

Tags: javascript, css, sass, gruntjs

I've tried a few things but can't come to a good solution.
I'm using grunt to compile my sass and minify my javascript.

Is it possible to autoload every .sass file and every .js file in a specific directory?

I've tried stuff like this

```
sass: {
            options: {
                sourceMap: false
            },
            dist: {
                src: 'src/sass/**/*.sass',
                dest: 'dist/css/style.css'
            }
        }
```

but this will only load the very first sass file. 
I'm not sure what concat even does but I tried it aswell and didn't find the solution I was looking for.

Basicly all files in the folder sass/ should be compiled to 1 big style.css file the same with javascript.

Sure I could manually import each file in a main.sass file or so, but I would love a autoload function so I don't get lazy and don't create new files because I would have to add them.

edit:

So with this

```
files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: "src/sass/",
                    src: ["**/*.sass"],
                    dest: "dest/css",
                    ext: ".css"
                }]
```

I can actually do what I want. The problem is my mixins get loaded too late and it's thorwing an error because it doesn't find the mixin I wanted to include.

Comment: It's explained [here](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass/blob/master/README.md) at *"Compile files in a directory"*.

Comment: Do I need to specific sub-directories aswell if I want these to be compiled aswell? How would I go about that.

Comment: Also how can I modify the order of compiling? My task has the problem that it compiles sass files that have mixins in them but compiles the mixins later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a format to generate a single output file from multiple source files:

```
concat: {
    whatever: {
        options: { separator: '\n' },
        src: ['src/sass/**/*.sass'],
        dest: 'build/tmp.sass'   // make sure the temporary build/ dir exists!
    }
}
```

It only works on tasks supporting combining multiple files; in this case the `grunt-contrib-concat` task.
It produces `dist/css/sass.tmp`, which you will need to process with the `sass` task:

```
sass: {
    dist: {
        files: [{        
            src: 'build/tmp.sass',
            dest: 'dist/css/style.css'
        }]
    }
}
```

You would make sure they are run in sequence with something like this:

```
grunt.registerTask( 'default', ['concat', 'sass'] ); // add your uglify/cssmin here
```

However, I don't recommend this, because the order of the sass files is uncontrollable, and it won't make mixin's available, even if they are compiled to css first - which is pointless, because they loose their 'mixin' format. It's best to run sass on a single source file and import your other files in that source file.

**Update**

Regarding auto-loading of mixin files,
the [SASS Reference](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#custom_importers) does mention you can use custom importers (written in Ruby) that take care of `@import`; I'm not sure whether this is only for top-level importing of files, or also for `@import mixin-name(foo)` within rules, but I don't think so.

There is an alternative approach you could use, based on `concat`, assuming that you have one main sass file. You would need to add a single `@import 'all-mixins'` to it. This `all-mixins.sass` is a generated file:

```
concat: {
    all_mixins: {
        options: { separator: '\n' },
        src: ['src/sass/mixins/*.sass'],
        dest: 'build/all-mixins.sass'
    }
}
```

And you would specify the [sass option **loadPath**](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass/blob/master/README.md#user-content-loadpath) to add `build/` to the path:

```
sass: {
    dist: {
        options: {
            loadPath: 'build/'
        },
        files: [{        
            src: 'build/tmp.sass',
            dest: 'dist/css/style.css'
        }]
    }
}
```

This is as close to auto-loading as it gets without extending sass itself.

Comment: alright so, there is no real good autoloading option while making sure that mixins get loaded first :/ thanks anyway :(

Comment: I updated the answer with a suggestion that may work for you.

Comment: alright thanks. Seems I think I'll stay away from the solution, I just will have to deal with adding the files manually.